# Laravel 7 no Verification email sent after a user registers

Tags: laravel, email

I followed the instruction of the Laravel documentation 7x for Email Verification.
I didn't do it at the very beginning and before this I made changes to the the users table adding columns like firstnane, familyname, city etc.
Since then I could register correctly without any email verification.
Today I decided to add this functionality but it doesn't work.
The register process is still going on but there is no email sent and the user is directly logged.
I use the

```
MAIL_MAILER=log
```

in my .env and other mails are correctly sent and visible in the logs file.

Here is the auth routes

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

I have a email_verified_at  column in the users table.

Any idea ?

Comment: did you make your User model implement the `MustVerifyEmail` contract/interface?

Comment: check your .env MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

Comment: `MAIL_MAILER=log` menas, your mail won't be sent. Your app will save all email in the log `/storage/log` directory,  loop up here, you will see the email message. You need to set as `MAIL_MAILER=smtp` or any other mail driver

Comment: I forgot it. I just added the use statement but not the implement.

Comment: Now email is sent but the user is still directly connected even before confirming email. Is this the normal behavior?

Comment: its okay, people forget that all the time ... i made an answer out of my comment/question for you

Comment: @sta I know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `User` model is not implementing the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` contract/interface.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
...

class User extends Model implements MustVerifyEmail
```

> "Once this interface has been added to your model, newly registered users will automatically be sent an email containing an email verification link." - [Laravel 7.x Docs - Email Verification - Model Preparation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification#model-preparation)

Comment: Please see my last comment above. My question is now, why is there no page displayed and saying a verification email has been sent to you. An other thing that is working is the inscription of the date in the users table column email_verified_at.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by this: "An other thing that is working is the inscription of the date in the users table column email_verified_at"

Comment: I mean that if I follow the sent link, the users table's email_verified_at is updated. The only thing the bothers me is the fact that just after registering the user is logged and when he follows the link is still is logged. There is no intermediate page explaining that he will receive a mail and that he must follow the link. I  expect I could prevent logging as long as the user has not confirmed.

Comment: the user is still a user they can login (this is normal, as they would need to be logged in to verify their email address)... did you read the part in the docs about restricting access to only verified users?

Comment: Do you mean the section "Protecting routes" of the guide in the Laravel documentation ?

Comment: yes that section of the documentation ... f you want them to see the verification notice page you would have to have your registration controller configured to redirect them there after registration ... which is the same route that the `verified` middleware will redirect them to (route named: `verification.notice`)

Comment: The trouble is I have a route that leads to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register but there is no register() function in the controller. Thus I cannot redirect.

Comment: define a method named `redirectPath` and have it return where you want them to go to

Comment: I added " return redirect('contact'); " for test as I don't know what is the route for teh verification notice and I have an error "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected "

Comment: sorry I meant `redirectTo` ... I told you what the route was named  `protected function redirectTo() { return route('verification.notice'); }`  ... but all of this is outside the issue of your posted question

Comment: Ok it works fine. Just differently of the way I was expecting (I wanted to prevent a user from being logged (= not to be a user yet) as long as the email is not verified) but I have to do an other way. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: no problem :) ... they need to be logged in to verify their email address so you can't do that ... you can restrict access to only verified users for routes with the `verified` middleware